# PyQt, Creating a popup in the window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create a GUI using PyQt5 and I want to add a popup similar to the one shown below(example taken from Discord because that's the first thing I could think of). How would I go about creating a popup inside of a window that I already have. I don't want to create a whole new window using something like a message box, the popup will be static(can't be moved around the screen manually), and should be able to be closed by clicking the close/x button, pressing esc, or clicking outside the widget

[image: Example of what I want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating an "embedded" widget is actually easy: the only thing you need to do is to set its *parent* as the window (or widget) when you create it. Reparenting can also be done after a widget is created (but a call to `show()` or `setVisible(True)` is *always* required).

The problem is that once the widget is shown "inside" the parent, access to other widgets is still possible.

The trick is to create a widget that *shadows* the content of the parent, and show the actual contents in a smaller widget. In order to do this you must install an event filter on the parent and always reposition the widget whenever the parent is resized.

Then, to provide a mechanism similar to that of QDialog, you can create an event loop and call its `exec()` just like a normal Qt dialog, and allow ui elements to interact with it.

[image: example login screenshot]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class LoginPopup(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            LoginPopup {
                background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 64);
            }
            QWidget#container {
                border: 2px solid darkGray;
                border-radius: 4px;
                background: rgb(64, 64, 64);
            }
            QWidget#container > QLabel {
                color: white;
            }
            QLabel#title {
                font-size: 20pt;
            }
            QPushButton#close {
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                background: none;
                border: 1px solid gray;
            }
        ''')

        fullLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget(
            autoFillBackground=True, objectName='container')
        fullLayout.addWidget(self.container, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.container.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

        buttonSize = self.fontMetrics().height()
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            '×', self.container, objectName='close')
        self.closeButton.setFixedSize(buttonSize, buttonSize)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        layout.setContentsMargins(
            buttonSize * 2, buttonSize, buttonSize * 2, buttonSize)

        title = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            'Enter an email address', 
            objectName='title', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(title)

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('EMAIL'))
        self.emailEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.emailEdit)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('PASSWORD'))
        self.passwordEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            echoMode=QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        layout.addWidget(self.passwordEdit)

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        self.okButton = buttonBox.button(buttonBox.Ok)
        self.okButton.setEnabled(False)

        self.emailEdit.textChanged.connect(self.checkInput)
        self.passwordEdit.textChanged.connect(self.checkInput)
        self.emailEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda:
                self.passwordEdit.setFocus())
        self.passwordEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.accept)

        parent.installEventFilter(self)

        self.loop = QtCore.QEventLoop(self)
        self.emailEdit.setFocus()

    def checkInput(self):
        self.okButton.setEnabled(bool(self.email() and self.password()))

    def email(self):
        return self.emailEdit.text()

    def password(self):
        return self.passwordEdit.text()

    def accept(self):
        if self.email() and self.password():
            self.loop.exit(True)

    def reject(self):
        self.loop.exit(False)

    def close(self):
        self.loop.quit()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.setGeometry(self.parent().rect())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        r = self.closeButton.rect()
        r.moveTopRight(self.container.rect().topRight() + QtCore.QPoint(-5, 5))
        self.closeButton.setGeometry(r)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.Resize:
            self.setGeometry(source.rect())
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def exec_(self):
        self.show()
        self._raise()
        res = self.loop.exec_()
        self.hide()
        return res


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('LOG IN')
        layout.addWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)

    def showDialog(self):
        dialog = LoginPopup(self)
        if dialog.exec_():
            print(dialog.email(), dialog.password())

import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: QDialog has its own way of dealing with parenthood, and it doesn't always allow correct management of resizing and displaying, so instead of trying to work around those "limitations", using a QWidget is much simpler and safer.

Comment: Hello, can you tell me what "doesn't always allow the correct management of resizing and displaying" this means? Does it mean creating custom Dialog by inheriting QDialog or using QDialog can be problematic?

Comment: @JacksonPro No, the problem raises when trying to embed the QDialog in a parent widget, instead of using the parent for modality. I didn't do much testing for this specific case, but I remember having some problems when trying to reparent a QDialog and changing its window flags (removing `Qt.Dialog` while leaving the other existing flags, in order to show it *inside* the parent), as there are some issues depending on the platform, when native dialog are used by default. You can obviously test it on your own and check the results.